# References to learn more about graph laplacian.

Tags: graph-theory, pr.probability, physics, spectral-graph-theory

I have vaguely heard of this connection between random matrix theory and graphs (the spectral gap of their laplacians) on compact Riemann surfaces.

- Can someone give a pedagogic reference which helps learn this subject?
- Also is there something called "free probability theory" which is somehow equivalent to random matrix theory?
- Would you call the usual QFT of Hermitian matrices a random matrix theory?

Comment: Why has this question been downvoted!?

Comment: think its borderline research level. there are large amts of refs easily located. see eg [network solutions](http://www.simonsfoundation.org/mathematics-and-physical-science/network-solutions/?redirect=%252Fmathematics-physical-sciences%252Ffeatured-articles) by Klarreich for a nice pop sci overview incl recent research

Answer (score 1):

Suggest these free available resources. Most textbooks on graph theory only glance at "free probability theory".

Lectures on the Combinatorics of Free Probability (London Mathematical Society Lecture Note Series): 
[http://www.amazon.com/Lectures-Combinatorics-Probability-Mathematical-Society/dp/0521858526](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521858526)

Speicher lectures: http://www.mast.queensu.ca/~speicher/papers/lectures-IHP.pdf

Comment: URL : http://books.google.com/books?id=zsw_-E-QrOkC&pg=PR7&source=gbs_selected_pages&cad=2#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: But do these references build the connection with grpahs on Riemann surfaces? (and may be their Laplacians) I m not able to locate it.